# How to make sure code runs before window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixpanel

I have a submit event so that when a form is submitted I make an AJAX API call to POST some information and then I want to run code within that success handler that tracks information in Mixpanel and then redirects the page. I currently have it where the page just redirects by itself without submitting the Mixpanel information.

I commented out the window redirect and then the mixpanel stuff starts getting logged.

Here is my code:

```
$.post('record', Record, function(data) {
    mixpanel.identify(data.user);
    mixpanel.people.set({
      '$email': data.user.email
    });
    return mixpanel.track('Event Created', {
      'User': data.user.email,
      'Event Date': Date.now(),
      'Event Name': $('#record-title').val()
    });

    // this ends up submitting without the mixpanel stuff submitting
    window.location.href = "https://" + window.location.host + "/records/dashboard";
});
```

What is the best way to make sure that the mixpanel stuff gets sent and then the window.location happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need to wait on [`mixpanel.track`](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.track) to finish

you can use the `callback` argument

> If provided, the callback function will be called after tracking the event.

```
$.post('record', Record, function(data) {
    mixpanel.identify(data.user);
    mixpanel.people.set({
      '$email': data.user.email
    });
    mixpanel.track(
      // event name
      'Event Created',
      // properties
      {
        'User': data.user.email,
        'Event Date': Date.now(),
        'Event Name': $('#record-title').val()
      },
      // callback
      function () {
        window.location.href = "https://" + window.location.host + "/records/dashboard";
      }
    );
});
```